# Groupby date and find number of occurrences of a value a in another column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My Dataset is looking like this

[image: Input dataset]

I would like to get the output something like this.

[image: Output dataset]
I need to group by date and find the occurrences if each feedback. In this case, i have 5 feedback types (namely 5,4,3,2,1)

Comment: df.groupby(['Date', 'Feedback']).size().unstack()

Answer (score 1):

This can work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

unstacked_df = stacked_df.unstack()
```

The next time you post, you could post a **reproducible code** so we could help you a little more.

Comment: The unstack function has arguments such as level, etc., you may work with this information.